# Closing editors of QAbstractItemView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html) to manipulate a queue. The problem is that the editor doesn't close and update the value in the model when the user hits the send button. This causes some frustration.

I've gone through the Qt docs, but I can't seem to find a simple way of closing the editor and committing the changes. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used

```
void ProjectExplorerView::CloseCurrentEditorIfOpen(bool commit)
{
   QWidget* w = indexWidget(currentIndex());
   if (w != nullptr)
   {
     if (commit) {
        commitData(w);
        closeEditor(w, QAbstractItemDelegate::SubmitModelCache);
     } else {
        closeEditor(w, QAbstractItemDelegate::RevertModelCache);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: BTW I think the commitData() is redundant.

Comment: The `commitData` is not redundant. Leaving it out closes the editor without the data getting committed.

Comment: the `QAbstractItemDelegate::SubmitModelCache` flag in `closeEditor` is supposed to submit it ala commitData AFAIK. Therefore it is redundant to call it before hand.... unless you have first hand knowledge otherwise?

Comment: I had just tried it out before commenting. Looking at the code of `QAbstractItemView::closeEditor`, passing in `SubmitModelCache` only means it will call [`QAbstractItemModel::submit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#submit). So this flag is only useful for caching data models and has nothing to do with committing what is in the editor to the model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you would have to track the currently open item through the selection model or the ItemView signals or `currentIndex()`, when you have `QModelIndex` of the item that is currently open you should be able to close it using `closePersistentEditor ( const QModelIndex & index )`

Comment: I think closePersistentEditor will only work if you used openPersistentEditor to create an editor, but I will give it a try.